# Connection Reset for long request processing

Tags: spring-boot, http, google-cloud-platform, tomcat, connection-timeout

I find that my springboot (2.7) application can fail to send response back with connection reset issue, but there's no error logs on my application so it should be somehow cut the connection by springboot.

This situation only occur when the application process the request longer than 60s. I have tried to increase the connection timeout, keep-alive timeout for tomcat, but does not work.

in configuration class:

```
  @Bean
  public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> tomcatCustomizer() {
    return (tomcat) -> tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers((connector) -> {
      if (connector.getProtocolHandler() instanceof AbstractHttp11Protocol) {
        AbstractHttp11Protocol<?> protocolHandler = (AbstractHttp11Protocol<?>) connector
            .getProtocolHandler();
        protocolHandler.setKeepAliveTimeout(120000);
        protocolHandler.setConnectionTimeout(120000);
        protocolHandler.setConnectionUploadTimeout(120000);
        protocolHandler.setMaxKeepAliveRequests(500);
        protocolHandler.setUseKeepAliveResponseHeader(true);
      }
    });
  }
```

in application.yaml:

```
server:
  tomcat:
    keep-alive-timeout: 120000
    connection-timeout: 120000
```

P.S. my application is deployed on GCP

Comment: There are many possible causes. Timeouts might be an issue or a change in network status. The key is to figure out what is causing the error. Sometimes it is caused by home Internet routers or Antivirus interfering with connections. Your question does not have details so all we can do is make generalizations and guesses. When I have this problem, I fire up WireShark which helps determine what/where/why the connection is terminating. The first step is to divide the problem in half. Is the problem client side or server (remote) side.